# Excel ::String cell value is not getting concatenated with integer in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

In this below code, tried to create a 10 cells with String value which will be sequentially increased like "BRT_1", "BRT_2", "BRT_3"...."BRT_10". But in excel, only BRT_ is entered not the integer value concatenated with "BRT_".

```
        for(r=1;r<10;r++)
        {
            sh.createRow(r);
            for(c=0;c<body.size();c++)
            {
                String value = body.get(c).toString();
                if(value == "BRT_")
                {
                    sh.getRow(r).createCell(c).setCellValue(value+r);
                }
                else
                    sh.getRow(r).createCell(c).setCellValue(value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you must use the .equals method to compare two strings: if (value.equals("BRT_"))

Comment: This is because `if(value == "BRT_")` will never be true since `==` is not the correct way to test for `String` equality. Correct way to do so is `if("BRT_".equals(value))`.

Comment: Thanks @jalynn2..it's my mistake..Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if(value == "BRT_")
{
    sh.getRow(r).createCell(c).setCellValue(value+r);
}
```

with

```
if("BRT_".equals(value))
{
    sh.getRow(r).createCell(c).setCellValue(value+String.valueOf(r));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arvind..yes i replaced.